# Running a loop inside Update()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I need to change the scale of an object based on a value from an array (data_int[]), it should increase if the value is increasing and vice versa. the code I tried does that but I can only visualize the end result. However, I need to visualize every step in the loop.

```
void Update()
{
    if (MyFunctionCalled == false)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++)
        {
            if (data_int[i] > data_int[i - 1])
            {
                transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
            }
            else if (data_int[i] < data_int[i - 1])
            {
                transform.localScale += new Vector3(-0.01f, -0.01f, -0.01f);
            }

        }
        MyFunctionCalled = true;
   }
  }     
 }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *visualize every step in the loop*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole loop is executed during 1 frame, you can't see the step by step. You can *"simulate"* the loop outside of the method `Update`

In example :

```
// initialize your iterator
private int i = 1;

// I removed the checks on MyFunctionCalled because this may be irrelevant for your question
void Update()
{
    // use an if instead of a for
    if (i < 25)
    {
        if (data_int[i] > data_int[i - 1])
        {
            transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
        }
        else if (data_int[i] < data_int[i - 1])
        {
            transform.localScale += new Vector3(-0.01f, -0.01f, -0.01f);
        }
        // this is the end of the supposed loop. Increment i
        ++i;
    }
    // "reset" your iterator
    else
    {
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly. Just need to point out that " i " should be initialized to 1 because I compare with i-1 in the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Coroutine` function to achieve your goal.

The line, `yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f)` will simulate waiting for .5 seconds before continuing. `yield return null`, `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame()`, and others may also be used to delay the execution of a `Coroutine`. More information about when each of these return may be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html). [This question on coroutines](https://answers.unity.com/questions/755196/yield-return-null-vs-yield-return-waitforendoffram.html) may also be useful.

```cs
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ScaleObject());
    }

    IEnumerator ScaleObject()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++)
        {
            if (data_int[i] > data_int[i - 1])
            {
                transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
            }
            else if (data_int[i] < data_int[i - 1])
            {
                transform.localScale += new Vector3(-0.01f, -0.01f, -0.01f);
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Coroutine is not good to use in Update() because Update cannot wait.

Comment: @SaadAnees There is nothing wrong with the use as it is being used here. It is being prevented from running more than once already by the `MyFunctionCalled` value.